# How can I check if a specific printer is invoked?

Tags: java, windows, printing

My problem is as follows.

A set of users[lying in the same network and all using windows xp] are using a specific network printer for printing their documents.

Now, whenever someone prints something, I need to check if that file-name starts with a specific code, and if so, I need to insert a row in one of the audit tables.

The problem is, the users can open any document and try to print them using this printer. How can I track that this printer is getting used, when my own piece of code is not invoking it at all?

Is there a way to catch this event of printing on a specific printer, irrespective of any knowledge of the source that fired this event? Is it at all possible to track this using java code?

Waiting eagerly for java gurus to respond. Thanks in advance for your kind co-operation.

Regards,
animark

Comment: Have inter-app communication, this has nothing to do with printing. Of course, this is assuming that your Java app is what is eventually going to print the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir. But that's exactly what my problem is. I wouldn't know what code is invoking the printer. Neither would I know, from which I.P the printer is tried to be invoked? Is there a way in java to detect  any source which tries to invoke a particular printer ?

Answer (score 0):

use some print Server like CUPSD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Never knew of what you mentioned. Will google it right away. A little more detail from you would have made my life a lot more easy though. :)